# Auto incrementing start form the second row and every second row in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, autoincrement

Subsequent to [Auto incrementing every second row in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324012/auto-incrementing-every-second-row-in-arcgis-desktop) , how can i start the auto increment from the second field (i work with 150 fields)

[image]

so the result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rec=0 
action = 'repeat'
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec
 global action  
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart
  return rec
 else:
  if action == 'count':
   rec += pInterval
   action = 'repeat'
   return rec
  elif action == 'repeat':  
   action = 'count'
   return rec

 autoIncrement()
```

Comment: If you used a modulus math function this function would be significantly faster than the current string comparison.

Comment: @Vince Absolutely! I was just trying to build upon the [original snippet](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137) provided in the [OP's first question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324012/auto-incrementing-every-second-row-in-arcgis-desktop).